# How to unconditionally exit/return a void method?

Tags: java, return

```
void A() {
  B();

  // return; <- compiler error "unreachable code"

  if (true) return; // <- this works

  // code that I will test later
  ...
  C(); 
  D();
}
```

This is what I do now. Is there a simple "`exit;`" or "`return;`" that will not yield `"unreachable code"` error without using the `if`?

---

Just to make it clear: `if (true) return;` **works** (with warning "Dead code" which I don't care and can suppress)!
if I simply use `return;` **only then** I get the `"unreachable code"` error.

Note: A simple "This can't be done without using `if`" is also an acceptable answer, provided a reference.

Comment: If you only want to test B() why not just call B()? Consider "cutting" your code into smaller methods to test on there own. As an idear most of the methods I write thease days are under tten lines. It takes some thinking but this would solve your problem without any haking. Just have the smallest method posible and write unit tests on this level.

Comment: If you want to avoid the warning, use an obfuscated `true` -- eg, call another method that always returns `true`, or use a `static` boolean that is set to `true`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Java does not support an unconditional return in the middle of a code block, since it doesn't "make sense" in the general scheme of things. (There are good reasons that the Java compiler does and must do fairly strong control flow analysis, and if the compiler allowed it the JVM verifier would still reject it.)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that there is:

```
if (true) return;
```

which will always call return, therefore the latter code is unreachable. If you use a **real** condition there's not going to be this warning.

But if you just want to test part of the method I would suggest just commenting the rest of the method that will be tested later.

Comment: This is not true. the code after `if (true) return;` *is* "reachable" - there is no error. I only get a warning "Dead code" which I don't care about. Maybe this is specific to platform/compiler? please read my edit.

Comment: @kobik - Just how could you get to the `c();` statement, with that `if(true) return;` sitting there??

Comment: @HotLicks, I don't want to get to `C();` - what I'm trying to do is a pseudo `exit;` or a simple *unconditional* `return;` (which is acceptable in JS for example) without using any `if`s.

Comment: @kobik I still don't understand your need for unconditional return? Is there any particular reason to that? I mean it seems you need it for testing purposes only, so it only seems as over-complicating it..

Comment: @kobik - That's why you use a method that always returns `true`, instead of the literal `true`.  The compiler will not "optimize away" the rest of the method in that case.

Comment: @HotLicks, <sigh> OK I suppose no one even understood what I wanted, and maybe I'm to blame b/c I'm really new to Java world. I don't want to use any `if`. I wanted to simply write `return;`. I guess Java does not support such functionality.

Comment: No, Java does not support that, since it doesn't "make sense" in the general scheme of things.  (There are good reasons that the Java compiler does and must do fairly strong control flow analysis.)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just comment the rest of the code?

```
void A() {
  B();

  /* code that I will test later
  C(); 
  D();
  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if (true) return;

This statement is yielding an unreachable code error because, compiler knows that this `if` block will be executed for sure(as you have put `true` condition). Your `if` block contains `return` statement which means at the statements below, will not be executed. Hence you get `"unreachable code"` error.